# How to trim each line in a heredoc (long string) in PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm looking to create a PHP function that can trim each line in a long string.

For example,

```
<?php
$txt = <<< HD
    This is text.
          This is text.
  This is text.
HD;

echo trimHereDoc($txt);
```

Output:

```
This is text.
This is text.
This is text.
```

Yes, I know about the trim() function, but I am just not sure how to use it on a long strings such as heredoc.

Comment: thanks for all the solutions.  I need to learn more regular expression.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
function trimHereDoc($t)
{
    return implode("\n", array_map('trim', explode("\n", $t)));
}
```

Comment: +1 becouse the more generic solution. (but, I don't like so compact lines)

Comment: Be aware that this will also strip out any return characters (\r) that may be paired up with the newlines (\n). The source file may be written with DOS or Apple line endings, but the resulting trimmed lines will all have Unix line endings. You can set the line endings you ultimately want in the first parameter of the explode() statement.

Comment: And if your trying to trim newlines from the string, simply omit the "\n" arg, in the implode function: return implode(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $t)));

Answer (score 11):

```
function trimHereDoc($txt)
{
    return preg_replace('/^\s+|\s+$/m', '', $txt);
}
```

`^\s+` matches whitespace at the start of a line and `\s+$` matches whitespace at the end of a line. The `m` flag says to do multi-line replacement so `^` and `$` will match on any line of a multi-line string.

Comment: nice RE.  need to keep snippets of this.

Comment: This function is actually incorrect as it will remove empty lines in a chaotic way too. The correct way is to use "/^[ \t\f]+|[ \t\f]+$/m" for pattern.

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution

```
<?php
$txtArray = explode("\n", $txt);
$txtArray = array_map('trim', $txtArray);
$txt = implode("\n", $txtArray);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function trimHereDoc($txt)
{
    return preg_replace('/^\h+|\h+$/m', '', $txt);
}
```

While `\s+` removes empty lines, keeps `\h+` each empty lines