# trim lines and shrink whitespaces using regex for multi line string

Tags: php, regex, pcre, multiline

I<s>'m using a [php function](https://github.com/fvsch/php-trim-whitespace)</s> want to create a function to trim all unnecessary white spaces from a multi line string.

The regex that it's not working is the one that removes spaces at the end:

```
// Always trim at the end. Warning: this seems to be the costlier
// operation, perhaps because looking ahead is harder?
$patterns[] = ['/ +$/m', ''];
```

Given the following string from a textarea:

```
 first  line... abc   //<-- blank space here
 second  is  here... def   //<-- blank space here
 //<-- blank space here
 fourth  line... hi  there   //<-- blank space here

 sith  is  here....   //<-- blank space here
```

There are blank spaces at the beginning and end of each line plus more than one between the words.

After I run the function:

```
$functions->trimWhitespace($description, ['blankLines' => false]);
```

This is what I get:

```
first line... abc //<-- blank space here
second is here... def //<-- blank space here
//<-- no bank space here
fourth line... hi there //<-- blank space here

sith is here....//<-- no blank space here
```

Why is it only removing the trailing space from the last line?

Comment: Have a try with [`'/ +\r?$/m'`](https://eval.in/730414) if unsure about type of line break used.

Comment: Since it is PHP, why not use `'/\h+$/um'`

Comment: @bobblebubble Yay! that's what it was missing. I'm currently in Linux, not sure if it'll work in Windows and Mac. Please put the solution in an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I already tried that one and it didn't work. I spent a couple of hours trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: Does it mean you want to also remove the CR symbol if it is present? I'd suggest `'/\h+(?=\r?$)/um'`

Comment: Clearly, do not use this stupid function, write your own it will be better.

Comment: Yeah, I ditched it in favor of something more simple, like one of the approaches in the answers. I'm trying to decide what's the best one.

Comment: If I were you, I will try a stream approach with user defined stream filters. I do not pretend it is faster or simpler but filters are reusable and it's from far the cleanest way. (one filter to trim leading whitespaces, one filter to transform tabs, one filter to remove duplicate spaces, and after you choose the filters you want when you want.)

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-php-streams-effectively/)

Comment: Well, I only do this, mainly, because I know some people tend to add an space but then a new line, so this way they do not waste up the remaining characters limit.

Comment: Related: *[How to trim each line in a heredoc (long string) in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655159)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may redefine where `$` matches using the `(*ANYCRLF)` verb.

See the following [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/Dak8xp):

```
$s = " ddd    \r\n  bbb     ";
$n = preg_replace('~(*ANYCRLF)\h+$~m', '', $s); // if the string can contain Unicode chars,
echo $n;                                        // also add "u" modifier ('~(*ANYCRLF)\h+$~um')
```

**Details**:

- `(*ANYCRLF)` - specifies a newline convention: `(*CR)`, `(*LF)` or `(*CRLF)`
- `\h+` - 1+ *horizontal* whitespace chars
- `$` - end of line (now, before CR or LF)
- `~m` - multiline mode on (`$` matches at the end of a line).

If you want to allow `$` to match at any Unicode line breaks, replace `(*ANYCRLF)` with `(*ANY)`.

See *`Newline conventions`* in the [PCRE reference](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

```
(*CR)        carriage return
(*LF)        linefeed
(*CRLF)      carriage return, followed by linefeed
(*ANYCRLF)   any of the three above
(*ANY)       all Unicode newline sequences
```

Now, if you need to

- Trim the lines from both start and end
- Shrink whitespaces inside the lines into just a single space

use

```
$s = " Ł    ę  d    \r\n  Я      ёb     ";
$n = preg_replace('~(*ANYCRLF)^\h+|\h+$|(\h){2,}~um', '$1', $s);
echo $n;
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/D6GE2s).

Comment: @ChazyChaz Reading your input is utf-8 and empty replacement is preferred I vote for Wiktors solution. Maybe you want to add the `u` flag (probably not needed here).

Comment: Well, my php output is utf-8, the input is the default one. I already use that flag to validate (preg_match). This is more detailed but I'd like a full approach (not just trailing), like Jan's answer, since I won't be using the function I found (I prefer something more simple).

Comment: What is the "full" approach? Trim the lines from both ends and shrink all 2+ whitespaces into 1?

Comment: Any way to combine this regex with one that trims the leading spaces? Normally, line breaks are after a dot so I prefer to use `ANYCRLF` for maximum compatibility for all OS.

Comment: Yes, basically that, I don't think there are more places where spaces can be stacked.

Comment: Wow, in one line! Thanks, that's beautifully working.

Answer (score 1):

Use a two step approach:

```
<?php

$text = " first  line... abc   
 second  is  here... def   
  <-- blank space here
 fourth  line... hi  there   

 sith  is  here....   ";

// get rid of spaces at the beginning and end of line
$regex = '~^\ +|\ +$~m';
$text = preg_replace($regex, '', $text);

 // get rid of more than two consecutive spaces
$regex = '~\ {2,}~';
$text = preg_replace($regex, ' ', $text);
echo $text;

?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/ERZUTt).

Comment: +1 for a full (two step) approach but it's not fully working on my end. I still get 1 blank space at the end of the lines (not the last one). However adding `\ +\r?$~m` does work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `/gm` instead of just `/m`

The code should become:
(this code won't work, the update one will)

```
$patterns[] = ['/ +$/mg', ''];
```

Working example here: https://regex101.com/r/z3pDre/1

**Update:**

The `g` identifier, don't work like this. We need to replace `preg_match` with `preg_match_all`

Use the regex without `g`, like this:

```
$patterns[] = ['/ +$/m', ''];
```

Comment: I'm getting this warning `Unknown modifier 'g'`.

Comment: @ChazyChaz try "mg" (not gm)

Comment: I'm using `'/ +$/mg'`.

Comment: use preg_match_all and don't add "g", updated the answer

Comment: I don't want to validate, I want to clean the string from leading/trailing/unnecessary blank spaces.

Comment: use preg_replace_all :)

Comment: Right! I'm going to check this and see what approach I take. Thanks.

Comment: welcome, please upvote the answer if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )`

so you want `preg_replace('/[\s]+$/m', '', $string)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 preg_replace('/*(.*) +?\n*$/', $content)
```

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KEhZc9/2)