# Replacing multi spaces/tabs [NO newline] with one space

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace multiple spaces and tabs with only one space. I don't want to replace any newline characters.
I'm new to REGEX and built this which does not work, still if you want to see it.

```
<pre>
<?php
$pattern = '/\s+[^\n]/';
$str = 'A string  with     variable   spaces  in   it
    I got some      tabs
I just have a newline and some space
';

$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($re, $replacement, $str);
?>
</pre>
```

This results in:

> Atringithariablepacesntotomeabsustaveewlinendomepace

Desired output

> A string with variable spaces in it
>   I got some tabs
>   I just have a newline and some space

Comment: See `preg_replace('~^\h+|\h+$|(\h){2,}~um', '$1', $str)` [demo](https://3v4l.org/8sCVk).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Plz add your comment as answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Also can you please explain the regex you used ?

Comment: I have [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42045891/3832970), please let know what you need me to clarify.